# Karma reporter with Grunt prints [object Object] instead of describe strings

Tags: gruntjs, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

With grunt, my failing tests output like so:

`Chrome 37.0.2062 (Mac OS X 10.9.5) [object Object] [object Object] [object Object] [object Object] [object Object] [object Object] [object Object] [object Object] [object Object] [object Object] [object Object] [object Object] [object Object] [object Object] [object Object] [object Object] [object Object] [object Object] [object Object] [object Object] should return full list if no filter options are set FAILED`

When I run the tests without grunt, the describe strings get printed just fine.

Grunt 0.4.5
Karma 0.12.23
Karma-Jasmine 0.2.0
Grunt-Karma 0.9.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was a karma-jasmine issue resolved with r0.2.1...

https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-jasmine/issues/46